# Is there a way to take input instead of the "TEXT" in this async function?

Tags: python, tkinter, async-await, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to make a GUI application to control my ELK-BlEDOM LED lights and I was wondering if this async fuction which is used to send commands to the bluetooth controller can take in user inputted commands instead of typing it in the code itself. Im very new to this please bare with me.

```
import asyncio
    from bledom.device import BleLedDevice
    from bleak import BleakScanner, BleakClient

    async def main():
        for device in await BleakScanner.discover():
            client = BleakClient(device)
            await client.connect()
            device = await BleLedDevice.new(client)

            await "TEXT"
asyncio.run(main())
```

I've tried to use the tkinter Entry but all I get is Timeout error.

Comment: Since when are strings await-able in python ? My personal opinion is to use a different thread for your `asyncio` code and leave your GUI in the mainthread happily ruling. However, there are things like asynctkinter (?) or how they named it and you might want to take a look at it to keep it *simple*.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know what exactly asyncio is, I do know you can pass
an argument to a function, you could take the user input, then say on a button click it sets that input to a variable and you pass that variable to your function.

Passing an argument can be done like this:

```
# In the () is what you name your arg that you'll use in the function

def main(a):
    # Then use "a" in the function for something
    a = do_stuff_with
    # you can then call on the function main(ARG_HERE) like bellow:
```

When you want to run the function with your argument you can
do that like this:

```
 # Set the argument or user input to a variable
 my_arg = doSomeCoolBluetoothStuff
 # Run the function passing the argument
 main(my_arg)
 # Then my_arg becomes a in your function
```

Thingamabobs also has a good point though, it should be ran on a different thread to keep from the main UI "freezing" when its running a computation or something of that nature. I don't know anything about the Bluetooth stuff, but if it does cause stutters or freezing look into running this in a background thread. There's a wealth of write ups on that. hopefully this can help at least get in the right direction =)